# How to subtract two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the difference between tow dates in javascript but my problem is that the first date is the currenet date of the PC :

```
today = new Date();
```

and the other date is a text format date like this for example:

```
other_date = '15.11.2013';
```

I want the today date to be same format as other_date and then subtract them , How can I change the format of the today to make the same as other_date ? and How I can make them both as date format to subtract them and get the difference correctly???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: also duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/543152/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use the `split` function to get the date parts of the date string:

```
var today = new Date();
var other_date = '15.11.2013';
var dateparts = other_date.split('.');
var otherDate = new Date(dateparts[2], dateparts[1]-1, dateparts[0]); // substract 1 month because month starting with 0

var difference = today.getTime() - otherDate.getTime(); // difference in ms
```